# Find one-to-one correspondence with "knnsearch" matlab function

Tags: matlab, knn, one-to-one

Is it possible to use the matlab function `Idx = knnsearch(X,Y)` in order to get a one-to-one correspondence between X and Y? I would like to exclude all values that have been already matched with the nearest neighbor in Idx.

If it's not, do you know another way to do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little ? Are you looking for the closest feature `X` for every `Y` ? If yes you could use `pdist2` or set the parameter `K` to 1 in `knnsearch`

Comment: This sounds more like an assignment problem to me, given some criterion for which matches to choose over others. MATLAB 2019b has [`matchpairs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matchpairs.html), but I've never used it.

Comment: @obchardon Yes, i'm looking for the closest feature _X_ for every _Y_. I report the same example that I found in Matlab regarding _knnsearch_ which is `openExample('stats/FindNearestNeighborsExample')`. If you run the code and then open _Idx_ you find that one index is repeted twice and I would avoid that this happens because I want to find a one-to-one correspondence. If I set the parameter _K_ to 1 I don't solve this problem.